# Can you still use XMPP with Firebase Cloud Messaging in a new project?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I tried setting up an authentication session with FCM today(August 2021) using the XMPP protocol.

(See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server
The fcm-xmpp server is still running and the first message in the authentication sequence works:

```
<stream:stream to="fcm.googleapis.com"
        version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client"
        xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
```

The server responds back with the various options.

The next step in the process should look like this:

```
<auth mechanism="PLAIN"
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">MTI2MjAwMzQ3OTMzQHByb2plY3RzLmdjbS5hb
mFTeUIzcmNaTmtmbnFLZEZiOW1oekNCaVlwT1JEQTJKV1d0dw==</auth>
```

From GOOGLE: (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server)

> Starting from March 2020, FCM stopped creating legacy server keys.
> Existing legacy server keys will continue to work, but we recommend
> that you instead use the newer version of key labeled Server key in
> the Firebase console.

They suggest using the new key, but using the new server key in the second part does not work.
The server returns with a failure and `<incorrect-encoding/>` - I assume this has to do with base 64 encoding.

Does anyone know if there is a solution to this or is XMPP not an option going forward anymore?

(I am using an esp8266 with an SSL connection)

Comment: I think the XMPP connection should still work, but... why would you use that instead of the more flexible, versioned REST API ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest)) or even the legacy REST API ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-using-the-legacy-app-server-protocols)).

Comment: I need to receive push notifications on an ESP8266. I can send push notifications from the device using REST but I am not able to receive them. I have gone through hundreds (literally) of documents trying to find out how to authenticate to the FCM rest server so that it would send me notifications but there is just not enough information. XMPP seemed as if it could work but now the auth key does not seem to be available anymore. (Any help on REST authentication? Please help here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68580946/trying-to-receive-push-notifications-on-esp8266-from-fcm

Comment: Ah, got it. I didn't even know it's possible to *receive* messages over XMPP. Given that XMPP is a connection oriented protocol, did you consider a more modern alternative like the Firebase Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore. Those are also connection oriented, and a lot more recent.

Comment: Yes, I can stream from firebase (I need practically real time) but once you have a lot of devices the cost will become enormous. The payload to the ESP is practically nothing so it would be far more efficient and use far less data if I could receive push notifications rather than keep alive packets. Unfortunately, like I said I need almost instant reaction and thus polling Firebase is not an option.

Comment: Not trying to convince you, but that polling can be prevented by implementing SSE as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming. At that point you're getting pretty close to the same infra as XMPP, but I get that the latter might be easier. I just have no recent experience with FCMs XMPP gateway.

Comment: Thanks yes, I did do the event streaming and it works nicely. Unfortunately event streaming sends keep alive packets that Firebase charges for. It adds up quickly, when you have a few thousand customers and since the customers are not charged for that service it becomes a costly affair for the manufacturer. i.e. the desire to implement push notifications. I still intend using the database but only once triggered by a "wake up event" from a push notification.